# Determine when urlsession.shared and Json parsing are finished

Tags: ios, json, swift, urlsession

I am downloading and then reading a json file. this json contains a list of files and their address on the server.

Everything works fine but I want to get the size of all files to download.

but I have some trouble to set up a completionblock that would indicate that everything is finished.

here is the code.

```
   jsonAnalysis {
        self.sum = self.sizeArray.reduce(0, +)
        print(self.sum)
    } here

func jsonAnalysis(completion:  @escaping () -> ()) {


    let urlString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")

        } else {
            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
                self.i = -1
                guard let array = json?["Document"] as? [Any] else { return }

                for documents in array {

                    self.i = self.i + 1
                    guard let VersionDictionary = documents as? [String: Any] else { return }
                    guard let DocumentName = VersionDictionary["documentname"] as? String else { return }
                    guard let AddressServer = VersionDictionary["addressserver"] as? String else { return }

                    self.resultAddressServer.append(AddressServer)
                    self.addressServer = self.resultAddressServer[self.i]
                    self.resultDocumentName.append(DocumentName)
                    self.documentName = self.resultDocumentName[self.i]

                    let url1 = NSURL(string: AddressServer)
                    self.getDownloadSize(url: url1! as URL, completion: { (size, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("An error occurred when retrieving the download size: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                        } else {
                            self.sizeArray.append(size)
                            print(DocumentName)
                            print("The download size is \(size).")

                        }
                    })

                }

            } catch {
                print("error")
            }

        }
            completion()

        }   .resume()

}

func getDownloadSize(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Int64, Error?) -> Void) {
    let timeoutInterval = 5.0
    var request = URLRequest(url: url,
                             cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
                             timeoutInterval: timeoutInterval)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        let contentLength = response?.expectedContentLength ?? NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown
        completion(contentLength, error)
        }.resume()
}
```

I would like to get the sum of the array at the end when everything is done, right now print(self.sum) is running before and shows 0.

I am not familiar with the completion and I am sure I am doing everything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `DispatchGroup`.

Before calling the inner asynchronous task `enter`, in the completion block of the inner asynchronous task `leave` the group.
Finally when the group `notifies`, call `completion`

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
for documents in array {
    ...

    let url1 = URL(string: AddressServer) // no NSURL !!!
    group.enter()
    self.getDownloadSize(url: url1!, completion: { (size, error) in
         if error != nil {
            print("An error occurred when retrieving the download size: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
         } else {
            self.sizeArray.append(size)
            print(DocumentName)
            print("The download size is \(size).")
         }
         group.leave()
     })
}
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    completion()
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly and give me the total size at the end as expected Thank you!!

Comment: You could always wrap an async call into another and use then have one callback for as soon as you trigger and another upon completion. Similar to how UIAnimation takes two blocks. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate)